# Excel VBA Array Ranges for a loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a loop function to refer to a range of cells, rather than typing in the worksheet names individually.

I've got this code that works:

```
Sub LoopTest()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'

'
' Loop Test

Dim SheetsArray As Variant
Dim i As Integer
SheetsArray = Array("Bun1", "Bun2")

For i = LBound(SheetsArray) To UBound(SheetsArray)
    With Worksheets(SheetsArray(i)).Select
        Range("A2:G60").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

But then this code doesn't when I try and get it to refer to a range instead:

```
Sub LoopTest()
'
'
' Loop Test

Dim Arr As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Worksheets("Names").Range("A2:A3")

Arr = rng

For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
    With Worksheets(Arr(i)).Select
        Range("A2:G60").Select
        Selection.ClearContents
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

I'm getting "Subscript out of range" error when I try and use it, however the worksheets all exist (the range has the same names as the first code). Debug is highlighting the

```
WIth Worksheets(Arr(i)).Select
```

line. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Cr1kk0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always get a 2 dimensional array when you assign a range to a variant so you need to specify both dimensions. There's also no need to select anything here:

```
For i = LBound(Arr, 1) To UBound(Arr, 1)
    Worksheets(Arr(i, 1)).Range("A2:G60").ClearContents
Next i
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thank you! Sorry, I don't have the reputation yet to upvote your answer.

Comment: You answer saved my life .