# Using VBA to assign range of cell values to array of variables

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA, to bear with me here.

I want to assign a set of variables the value of a set of ranges ie. run a brief code to simplify the following

```
Dim Sample 1 as string
Sample1 = activeworksheet.range("C17").value

Dim Sample 2 as string
Sample2 = activeworksheet.range("C18").value}
```

and so on

Following an excelfunctions.net tutorial, I know that I can shorten the declaration to

```
Dim Sample(1 to 20) as a string
```

But the tutorial drops it there(because it's a tutorial about names), suggesting I populate it as follows

```
sample(1)=activesheet.range("C7").value
sample(2)=activesheet.range("C7").value
```

and so on

I found the discussion below to be on the right track to answer my quest, but I am having trouble applying it to my situation. ([Excel VBA Array Ranges for a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938768/excel-vba-array-ranges-for-a-loop))

As a follow up note, I am ultimately trying to assign values to these variables for use in the following procedures, rather than declaring and assigning them each time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should :

- Define the range you want to retrieve data
- For each cell of the range, retrieve your datas

  ```
  dim tab() As string, cell as range, i as integer
  i = 0
  redim tab(0)
  for each cell in ActiveWorksheet.Range("C1:C20")
      tab(i) = cell
      i = i + 1
      redim preserve tab(i)
  next
  ```

edit : I indent the code to display it correctly

Comment: All sets of code worked, the code that Maxime suggested had the added bonus of preserving that output for later use. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim sampleArr(1 To 20) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

i = 1
Set rng = Range("C1:C20") 

For Each cel In rng
    sampleArr(i) = cel.Value
    i = i + 1
Next cel
For i = LBound(sampleArr) To UBound(sampleArr)
    Debug.Print sampleArr(i)
Next i
```

Also, if you know the range you want to put into an array, you can simply set an array to that range:

```
Sub test()
Dim sampleArr() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

i = 1
Set rng = Range("C1:C20") ' Note, this creates a 2 Dimensional array

sampleArr = rng ' Right here, this sets the values in the range to this array.

For i = LBound(sampleArr) To UBound(sampleArr)
    Debug.Print sampleArr(i, 1) ' you need the ",1" since this is 2D.
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The second part of the answer is the easier method, which I assume is what the OP was expecting

    `Dim Arr() As Variant ' declare an unallocated array.`
    `Arr = Range("A1:C5")' Arr is now an allocated array`

Answer (score 1):

Additional way to the above you can only use:

```
Arr = ActiveWorksheet.Range("C1:C20").Value
```

Then you can directly use:

`Arr(i,1)` where `i` is C1 to C20 range!