# Defining public ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I create in a sub custom ranges using the following code:

```
Dim custom_range(1 To 5) As Range

Set custom_range(1) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Countries").Columns(5).Cells
Set custom_range(2) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Operations").Columns(2).Cells
Set custom_range(3) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Costs").Columns(2).Cells
Set custom_range(4) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Revenue").Columns(2).Cells
Set custom_range(5) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FS").Columns(2).Cells
```

The issue I'm facing is that I use the same code in several subs, but I'd like to do it only once.

Creating public sub and then calling it unfortunately doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried public custom_range() as variant?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706754/using-vba-to-assign-range-of-cell-values-to-array-of-variables

Comment: If you have ugly, repetitive, inefficient code that works as intended but that you'd like to improve, put it up for peer review on [codereview.se] (all of it, not just a context-less snippet like this). Describe its purpose, your design decisions and your concerns, and reviewers will be happy to help you make it more efficient, readable, maintainable, performant, secure, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might get "rotten tomatoes" here for posting this, but you could use the simple `Init` sub below.

Just put it in a separate code module, and everywhere you need to use these `custom_range` array, just Call this sub.

**Code (in Init Module)**

```
Option Explicit

Public custom_range(1 To 5) As Range

Sub Init()

Set custom_range(1) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Countries").Columns(5).Cells
Set custom_range(2) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Operations").Columns(2).Cells
Set custom_range(3) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Costs").Columns(2).Cells
Set custom_range(4) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Revenue").Columns(2).Cells
Set custom_range(5) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("FS").Columns(2).Cells

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd throw you one juicy rotten tomato, but given that's all the context we have, "use a global variable" is pretty much the only reasonably possible answer to give... so have an upvote =) ...I hope OP gives reviewers more meat to chew on over on CR though.