# Search previous rows until value not found and dynamic calculation

Tags: excel, vba

I am newer to VBA. Currently trying to write a script that will store a temporary value from each row, and then search previous rows for that value. If there is a match, then I would like to store new temporary values and perform a simple calculation. This process would continue until there aren't any more matches within previous rows.

```
lastr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Range("A1:A120000").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For m = 1 To lastr
Select Case ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 9).Value

              'store all of these values for each row. I can add conditional statements later.

              lim_1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 17).Value
              lim_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 20).Value
              lim_3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 21).Value
              
              lower_bound1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 22).Value
              upper_bound1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 24).Value
              
              upper_bound2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 25).Value
              upper_bound2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 26).Value
              
              dash_end = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 6).Value
              seq_num = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 2).Value
    
              target_value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 9).Value


'  ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The goal here is to see if target_value is found in any cell above, within my provided range for now. If target_value is found, then I would store temporary values and perform a simple calculation. Also, if there is a match with the target value, then the next target value would change. For example, if my target valuewas 6, I would search previous rows for 6 in column D. If I had a match, the next target value would become that rows column I value.

```
            Set rngRangeToLookAt = ActiveSheet.Range("D1:D724")
            Set FoundCell = rngRangeToLookAt.Find(target_value, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

                    
            If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
             
             'These would be the values I would be storing if I found a match during my previous row scans
              rngFirstAddress = FoundCell.Address

                   target_value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 9).Value
                   temp_dash = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 6).Value
               
                   temp_lim_1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 17).Value
                   temp_lim_2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 20).Value
                   temp_lim_3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 21).Value
              
                   temp_lower_bound1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 22).Value
                   temp_upper_bound1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(m, 24).Value

               
              'Simple Calculation performed below. 
                
                Simple_Calc = temp_dash * dash_end
                dash_end = Simple_Calc
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("My List").Cells(FoundCell, 8).Value = dash_end

                Do            
                    Set FoundCell = rngRangeToLookAt.Find(target_value, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
                Loop Until FoundCell Is Nothing Or FoundCell.Address = rngFirstAddress
                
            End If
```

The provided photo shows an example of what I am trying to accomplish.
[image]

Comment: I might try to split up you "My Goal Here..." Line into a few lines for ease of reading

Comment: Thanks, just made that edit. Hopefully it helps someone provide some assistance.

Comment: Okay, so where exactly are you running into trouble? I have a couple of notes: 1) Start your sub with an [**Option Explicit**](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html) statement, then make sure all variables are declared. 2) Why are you looping `FoundCell` to starting address or nothing? You can just `Set FoundCell = nothing` 3) Move `Set rngRangeToLookAt...` before you for loop, no reason to set it multiple times. 4) exchange your `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet` for definite sheet references, and consider using a `With` Statement with you have a list of commands

Comment: Cont: ... that all reference the same Object. [With Sheet Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-with-statements) 4) Arrays are going to make this much faster. [Loop Range as Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938768/excel-vba-array-ranges-for-a-loop) , 5) you Set `**upper_bound2** = ...Cells(m, 25)...` then immediately the same var again `**upper_bound2** =...Cells(m, 25).Value...`